# New EE3 installation and other SQL-base

Tags: database, update, migration, install, database-migrations

Sorry for my bad English.

I have a website on EE1. I want EE3. There is a big problem with convert database (old PHP and MySQL on the server and can't converted via EE2, and if i update the PHP and MySQL, my EE1 will not work).

That's what I came up with: put on a separate host of EE3 and just fill the database manually. Then update the PHP and MySQL on the main server, install EE3 and add there the backup of the newly database.

Is this a good idea? What should I know?

Answer (score 1):

Never ever do direct EE1 to EE3. First of all upgrade EE1 to EE2. That will make necessary changes to your database. (Remember change all the plugins with EE2 version otherwise backend and/or frontend may crash.)

After upgrading it to EE2, upgrade your server then upgrade site to EE3.

Remember to:

1. Always take a backup copy of your site.
2. Its good to upgrade site on local like xampp. Fast and easy.
3. Always upgrade plugin after upgrading site.
4. Test the whole site to confirm everything is working fine.
5. EE1 to direct EE2.11 may cause some issue. Better option is to upgrade it to first minimal version of EE2 (Like EE2.5) and then upgrade to maximum version of EE2 [just for not taking chance to direct jump.]